# Google Apps Script for creating id

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google apps script to automatically create a doc when someone submits the form . But now I want to make an Id no. for each submission as well. There is a section in the form where you have to select one among 4 options (mechanical,nonmechanical, It, Open) . I want to create a sequence of numbers but the serial number will be starting with initial letters of whats he selects in that field. For example if someone choose mechanical then the id will be "mc001". Again if the second person enters it then it will be "it002" Can't find the proper way to execute this thing in apps script. Please help .

FOrm Link : https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdTDh_c_ThUKu6-_CmsaYnVZKFnHEFji-eb4_i0cvRCePxlaQ/viewform

apps script code

```
  function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Name = e.values[1];
  var class1 =  e.values[2];
  var team = e.values[3];
  var project = e.values[4];
  var phone = e.values[5];
  var idnumber = e.values[6];
  
  //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1nVMeanqeOL3fgEcjlzoq1u_FKu5E9Ta5IEO0ng-mt6Y"); 
  
  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1NeEHCsNhbQ0bAfcd3o-7X4SAhyEWXx1W")
  var copy = file.makeCopy(team + ',' + project, folder); 
  
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{name}}', Name); 
  body.replaceText('{{class1}}', class1);  
  body.replaceText('{{team}}', team); 
  body.replaceText('{{type}}', project); 
  body.replaceText('{{no}}', phone); 
  body.replaceText('{{id}}', idnumber);
  
  //Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

I would like to execute this thing and hope to get the id automatically generated in the spreed sheet and then get saved in a section within the doc

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `var idnumber` line in your function with this:

```
  const idnumber = insertUniqueId_(e, 6);
```

...to put unique IDs in column `G`. Here's one possible implementation of the `insertUniqueId_()` function:

```
/**
* Inserts a unique ID in the row where a new form response was stored.
*
* @param {Object} e The "on form submit" event object.
* @param {Number} uniqueIdColumnIndex The zero-indexed column number of the unique ID column.
* @return {String[]} The unique ID.
*/
function insertUniqueId_(e, uniqueIdColumnIndex) {
  const uniqueIdCell = e.range.offset(0, uniqueIdColumnIndex, 1, 1);
  const uniqueId = Utilities.getUuid();
  uniqueIdCell.setValue(uniqueId);
  return uniqueId;
}
```

The code will insert [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) like `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000`. To insert IDs like `mc001` or `it002`, replace `Utilities.getUuid()` with a call to your own function that returns IDs of your liking. It is likely that you will have to check existing IDs to avoid collisions. See the `getId_()` function in [Create one sequential ID Generator across two different Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/130462067?msgid=130619404) for sample code that avoids collisions.